# Python item type Changes Randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, assert

Something really strange is happening with my python script, and item type gets changed without clear reason.

I have:

```
for key in match_phrases:
    for phrase in match_phrases[key]:
        print(match_phrases[key])
        print(phrase)
        assert isinstance(phrase, str) #FAILS TUPLE
```

first print command prints:

```
['DEVICE NAME', 'PRODUCT NAME', 'PRINTER NAME', 'IP CAMERA NAME', 'ROUTER NAME']
```

then second one prints:

```
(1, 'PLEASE CONFIGURE THE PASSWORD')
```

where did that values came from?

I'm expecting it to iterate over the list's values ie: 'DEVICE NAME' etc...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share what match_phrases looks like/a reproducible example

Comment: @EmiOB I'm trying, what's strange is that I never change the values of match_phrases...

Comment: Please show us the output of `print(match_phrases)` *before* entering the loop.

Comment: @larsks first loop?

Comment: Yes, we are interested in the value of `match_phrases`, and you have not yet updated your question to show this information.